# sqlite: temporary table/view in a read-only db?

Tags: sqlite, temporary-objects

It seems that sqlite won't allow me to create a temporary view in a read-only db. Am I missing something? If it's TEMPORARY, I figured db connection mode shouldn't matter.

I even specified "PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY" -- it didn't help.

Is there a reasonable alternative to using views?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary view that references data in the main db.

```
CREATE VIEW temp.userview AS select userid, firstname, lastname from main.usertbl;
```

Then access the view like such...

```
SELECT * from temp.userview;
```

Comment: This does not work for the case when `pragma query_only = 1` for the database connection.  The OP didn't say how the DB was read-only, but that matters.  If the DB is *read-only in the file system* and `pragma query_only = 0`, the connection does allow temp views, at least on Windows 10.