# Can SQLite return default values for non-existent columns instead of error?

Tags: sqlite

I know how to use `IFNULL` to get default values for non-existent rows or null values, but for creating queries that are compatible with older schema versions, it would be nice to be able to do this:

Schema v1: `CREATE TABLE Employee (Name TEXT, Phone TEXT)`

Schema v2: `CREATE TABLE Employee (Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Address TEXT)`

Theoretical backward compatible query:
`SELECT Name, Phone, IFNULL(Address, '') FROM Employee`

Obviously this doesn't work for a file created with schema v1. Is there some way to do this though?

There are 2 alternative workflows, but both are rather annoying. Either 1) update the old db by adding missing columns (which would start with null values); or 2) build the query code dynamically based on schema version.

Comment: If you a column does not exist then you can not query it. So you have to choose between one of the options you suggested. I would check on program start if the DB has the column and if not create it. This is BTW how Android programs handle schema changes.

Comment: The problem with that approach is it requires a writable database, or making a copy before modifying it. Either way it's bad for large SQLite databases which are sometimes used as scientific data formats (not an intended usage of course, but it happens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a temporary view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404572/sqlite-temporary-table-view-in-a-read-only-db) that references a particular schema, substituting default values (or even transforming other data) for individual columns which differ between the *base* schemas.

[Sqlite views](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) can even be made modifiable by defining appropriate [triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

This still requires programming some conditional logic upon connection, but it would allow more uniform queries and interaction with different versions of the schema.

The suggested syntax would perhaps be convenient in some limited cases, but this approach is much more useful since it can be expanded beyond simple "if column exists" Boolean operations and instead could be used to perform dynamic transformation of one schema into another, perhaps joining tables and providing more advanced logic for updates of differing schema, etc.

Pseudo code mixed with view definitions to demonstrate:

```
db <- Open database connection
db_schema <- determine schema version

If db_schema == 1 Then
    db.execute( "CREATE VIEW temp.EmployeeX AS
                 SELECT Name, Phone, '' AS Address 
                 FROM main.Employee;" )
Else If db_schema == 2 Then
    db.execute( "CREATE VIEW temp.EmployeeX AS
                 SELECT Name, Phone, Address 
                 FROM main.Employee;" )
End If

#Later in code
   data <- db.getdata("SELECT Name, Address 
                       FROM EmployeeX")
```

If you're really averse to conditional statements for the schema this may still be annoying, but it would at least *reduce/eliminate conditional statements throughout the code*--ideally occurring as part of the connection logic at one location in the code.

You might further notice that *this pattern is really what object-oriented programming is supposed to solve*.  There's no mention of the language in the question, but a well-designed object model could be created in a similar fashion so that all database access is done through a unified interface.  The implementation details for different schemas are internal to different objects that derive (i.e. implement interfaces and/or inherit from base class) from a basic set of interfaces.  Consider the language you're using to see if the problem could be solved this way.

Comment: Despite the other answer on SO (linked to in my answer), my testing shows that sqlite does not allow creating a temporary view when the `pragma query_only = 1` is set.  There are other ways that a database can be read-only, like with file permissions, but I have not tested all possibilities.  I couldn't find a published solution for opening on DB as read-only but still allowing temporary views to be defined.  This does not completely ruin my answer as a solution, but I'm not sure yet if it would work for the scenario mentioned by the OP in comments.

Comment: Testing indicates that on a Windows machine, if the DB is read-only in the file system but `pragma query_only = 0`, then creation of temp views are allowed!  So at least this configuration supports the OP's read-only scenario.

Comment: Yeah I was mostly thinking of the file permissions aspect. I think this is a decent solution. Although it would be even nicer to combine the two approaches: `CREATE VIEW temp.EmployeeX AS SELECT Name, Phone, IFNULL(Address, ''), IFNULL(ZipCode, '')`, etc. This way the query code could truly look like it was always dealing with the latest schema (with allowances for default/null values from old schema).